# Rails - find_by_* route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In products_controller.rb

```
  # GET /search/'brand'
  def brand
    @product = Product.find_all_by_brand(params[:brand])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # brand.html.erb
    end
  end
```

In routes.rb

```
match '/search/:brand' => 'products#brand'
```

If I try accessing `localhost:3000/search/Apple` I get the following error `Couldn't find Product with id=Apple`

Is there anything that I'm missing? Are there any other files that I should handle?

**Update**

Now I'm getting `undefined method 'size' for nil:NilClass` and I'm not even sure what I changed.

The query executed by rails is `select "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."brand" = 'Apple' ORDER BY last_seen DESC` and they seem to return the correct products.

Application Trace

> app/views/products/_product.html.erb:1:in
>   `_app_views_products__product_html_erb___2255278_29707176'
>   app/views/products/brand.html.erb:1:in`
>   _app_views_products_brand_html_erb___464952485_38589588'
>   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:52:in `brand'

Comment: @house9, I'm sorry but I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: show the view code `app/views/products/_product.html.erb` and the calling code `app/views/products/brand.html.erb` - you have a nil object, maybe where you expect to have a product object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, the erb page was receiving `product` instead of `products`. Typing error.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in your controller indicate that you might want to try /search/brand/Apple.

Comment: `rake routes` returns me  `/search/:brand(.:format) products#brand` and isn't it the convention to write it that way? (I'm mimicking what's given by the default `show`)

Comment: Did you copy and paste all the code in your controller from another one? Something funky is going on. Also did you do a rake db:migrate?

Comment: What do you mean by something funky? Everything is written from scratch from examples in books/websites

Comment: Rails doesn't think that you have an attribute of brand for the model Product. Did you do a rake db:migrate and do you see brand column in your db?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that the brand attribute is there cause I'm printing it out just fine.